# Why isn't  the node ID available as "replacement pattern" for the title link?

Tags: 7, views

I have a simple view for a node using an "unformatted list" and fields. I want to link the title to another URL and pass the NID. However, as "replacement pattern" I only have the "[title]" token.
When I add the NID field to the view I can link it just fine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've to add the nid field and exclude it from display, after your NID must be before your title and you'll have access to it.

Even, if is not right, normally you'll have it.

Answer (score 1):

Yvan is right: If you want any link reference, that reference field needs to be added before active (title) field. In that way, you can use "[id]" in your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rearrange and place the Nid (Nid) at the top ( first position )